# Creating a batch file to delete multiple, separated subdirectories

Tags: batch-file

I am attempting to delete folders (and their contents) under the following directory structure: `C:\Root\*\Folder`, where * is a variable, single parent directory. I tried using:

```
rmdir /s /q "C:\Root\*\Folder"
```

However, I learned wildcards may only appear in the last directory. I found a similar problem involving copying files to a common destination. The solution was:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %m in (`dir /b c:\users`) do copy "C:\Users\%m\AppData\Roaming\LordEpicalsFiles\Info.txt" "C:\My_Files\%m_Info.txt"
```

[(Original Post)](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/69008-63-folder-wildcard)

However, my attempt to parse and then apply the code failed. Here is my attempt:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %m in (`dir /b C:\Root:`) do rmdir /s /q "C:\Root\%m\Folder"
```

Any comments and thoughts are greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi @Marged. Do you mean for /d instead of for /f?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This here will give you a list of directories in C:\users:

```
for /d %d in ("C:\Root\*") do echo %~nd
```

Depending if you need the full path (that means `C:\Root\` included) you can leave the `~n` out

So this (use with care) will delete what you want:

```
for /d %d in ("C:\Root\*") do echo rd "%d\Folder" /S /Q
```

(Remove the `echo` when you are sure this does what you want)

Please note that I wrapped the path in quotation marks, this is necessary when your path (unlike the example) contains spaces.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your code, @Marged! Unfortunately, it did not seem to work. I copied it into a new batch file--substituting in my actual directories--but the target folders remain. I remember in the post I linked that spaces in the path might be a problem, but I am unsure.

Comment: did you remove the echo from the command ? It is there to safe you from deleting something accidentally. If you see the correct command with the correct path on screen you can remove the echo and run the command again. Otherwise I could send you a script that automatically wipes out your complete harddisk without you knowing ;-)

Comment: You might need to use % twice: %%. What I wrote above works on the command line, in a batch you sometimes have to adjust the syntax

Comment: Thank you @Marged for reminding me about the double %; I am scripting a .bat and not using command line. However, it did not work with the % change. Allow me to post the actual code. `for /d %%d in (K:\Programs\4. PortableApps\PortableApps\*) do echo rd "%%d\Data" /S /Q`. Let me note that the command prompt flashes, but it immediately disappears, even with echo. I get the same results omitting echo.

Comment: I made a change to my answer: please add some quotation marks to the path you scan. In order to be able to see what your batch file is doing you should skip the echo off at the beginning of the file and add a pause command at the end of the file

Comment: Oh boy, it works! :) Thank you kindly for helping me. A follow-up question would be "Is there a way to exclude deleting certain Folder under a * or a set of * (while deleting the rest)? I am currently looking up how write that. Thanks again!

Comment: You could start with the first example in my answer and check if the folder that comes along is one you want to delete in or not.