# Excluding folders from %% parameter in Windows command line

Tags: batch-file, command-line, parameters

I would like to modify the following code to better target a set of folders.

I have the following folder structure:

- C:\Root\Dir1\Data, C:\Root\Dir2\Data, ...
- D:\Root\Dir1\Data, C:\Root\Dir2\Data, ...

The C: contains working copies, and the D: contains backup copies to be restored on-demand. [With the help of @Marged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682388/creating-a-batch-file-to-delete-multiple-separated-subdirectories), I utilize the following batch file:

```
for /d %%g in ("C:\Root\*") do rd /s /q "%%g\Data"
xcopy /s /q "D:\Root" "C:\Root"

pause
```

I now need a way to specify `%%g` to exclude folders in `C:\Root\*`. In example, I want line 1 to delete `C:\Root\Dir1\Data` and `C:\Root\Dir2\Data` but not `C:\Root\Dir3\Data`. It is required to make the exclusions explicit, as the set of inclusions change. I also need line 2 to better target folders. However, I believe that can be accomplished with XCOPY's `/EXCLUDE:"D:\Root\Dir3"` switch.

Thank you very much for reading and in advance for any discussion! :)

Comment: `... do if "%%~g" neq "C:\Root\Dir3" rd ...`?

Comment: Sorry for my inexperience, @Stephan. Would it look like `for /d %%g in ("C:\Root\*") do if "%%~g" neq "C:\Root\Dir3" rd /s /q "%%g\Data"`? I am trying it now.

Comment: It works! So simple; thank you @Stephan :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `... do if "%%~g" neq "C:\Root\Dir3" rd ...?` –  Stephan